# Editing / updating Excel table with Delphi AdoTable / Grid

Tags: database, excel, delphi, ado, delphi-xe5

I am trying to read-write from-to an Excel 2000 file in XE5-Delphi with a TADOTable and Grid component. Reading is working but when try to change some fields receive this:

"insufficient key column information for updating or refreshing"

Try to change cursor type, locking type, anything I found in the forums, did not work. Most of the recommendations are to define an index key, but this is Excel, so all are useless.

My code is:

```
Begin
  MastTable.FormMast.ADOTableMast.DisableControls;
  MastTable.FormMast.ADOTableMast.Edit;

  for i := 0 to SrcList.Items.Count-1 do
  begin
    MastTable.FormMast.ADOTableMast.First;

    while not MastTable.FormMast.ADOTableMast.EOF do
    begin;

      MastTable.FormMast.ADOTableMast.Edit;

      if MastTable.FormMast.ADOTableMast.FieldByName('FieldNames').Value = SrcList.Items[i] then 
        MastTable.FormMast.ADOTableMast.FieldByName('FieldNames').Value:='Yes'
      else 
        MastTable.FormMast.ADOTableMast.FieldByName('FieldNames').Value:='';

      MastTable.FormMast.ADOTableMast.Post;
      MastTable.FormMast.ADOTableMast.Next;
    end;
  end;

  MastTable.FormMast.ADOTableMast.Refresh;
  MastTable.FormMast.ADOTableMast.EnableControls;
End;
```

My connection string is:

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=N:\DP-DATA\Lee_County\LCPA\DistPropLCPA_Filters.xls;Mode=ReadWrite;Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:System database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="";Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=35;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;

Using Windows Vista Ultimate 64bit, Microsoft Database Engine 32bit installed.

Could anybody help me?

---

After three days and 66 visitors, it seems this is a difficult question. Frankly, I am very surprised that nobody could (wants?) help me. I feel forced myself to simplify the question: COULD ANYBODY SHOW ME AN EXAMPLE CODE IN XE5-DELPHI WHICH COULD READ AND WRITE EXCEL-2000 FILES? NOT GUESSES, OPINIONS, IDEAS, ADVICES! A FULLY FUNCTIONAL PROGRAM WITH COMPILED VERSIONS RUNNING ON XP, VISTA, WIN7 32/64 BIT MACHINES?! IS THIS REALLY SO DIFFICULT IN XE5-DELPHI????

Comment: How's your excel schema? you've defined a key column (ID for example)?

Comment: Hi Augustin, Thank you for your reply, sorry for the delay in mine. No, I haven't an ID column, but could put it, no problem. How could this help me?

Comment: Need an identifier column to know how to update the table

Comment: Ok, I have it. So what? Still the same error message. I guess something is with the connection string or the OLE Provider, but could not work it out. A very strange behaviour is this: When I have the form file containing my ADOTable component open additionally receive this: "Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or refresh the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need to have permission to view and write its data". If the form file is not opened in the IDE, at running this message is not appearing!